# How to know a program is being executed on GPU or CPU on Ubuntu?

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, cpu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and running my program to train a DeepLearning model. The epoch number seems to be big but the program is too slow. I wanna make sure my program is running on GPU?

How could I know that?

Thanks!

Comment: just use nvidia-smi and look at GPU utilization

Comment: What kind of program are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using an Nvidia GPU.

The simplest way to achieve this is to type the following command inside a terminal:

> watch -n 1 nvidia-smi

This will give you continuous update (every second) without filling the terminal with the output.

You will be able to check which processes are making use of your GPU, the allocated memory, the temperature and used power, etc.

[image: nvidia-smi]